# Change attributes of one node

Tags: r, igraph

How to change a color label node from its id or name?

Ex: I want to change label color node name="4" or id=3

```
g9<- graph(c(0,1,0,2,0,3,1,4,1,2,3,4,3,5,4,5,5,2),n=6,dir=FALSE)
V(g9)$name<-c(1:6)
V(g9)$label<-V(g9)$name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`V(g9)$color` is an array of colors.

To change color of a specific node say 2:
`V(g9)$color[2] ="#343434FF"`

If you want different color for each node, you can specify `rainbow(n)` where n is number of nodes and this function generates a array of colors and then you can specify: `V(g9)$color=rainbow(9)`

Also note: To get a list of vertices or nodes you can get them: `V(g9)`
and then if you decide to change the color of vertex 5, you can use `V(g9)$color[which(V(g9)==5)]="#434344"`
where, `which(V(g9)==5)` matches to vertex or node 5.