# Recode vertex attributes in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph with an attribute that is a character. I want to convert the character into a numeric variable:

```
#install.packages(c("igraph", "igraphdata"))
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
data(macaque)
get.vertex.attribute(macaque,"shape")
```

How do I convert the "shape" attribute from "square"/"circle" (character) to 0/1 (numeric) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I am finding that the type of `V(macaque)$shape` reverts to character, even when I specify numeric values.

Until we solve that: a workaround is to add a new attribute, `Shape` (with upper-case `S`), as follows.

```
V(macaque)$Shape <- ifelse(V(macaque)$shape == "square", 0, 1)
```

EDIT: you could then assign the values as in the answer from G5W; there is also an argument for not modifying existing attributes.

Answer (score 2):

If you just store the new values into the old attribute, it will keep everything as character values. You can get around this by storing the new values, deleting the existing attribute, then creating a new attribute with the same name.

```
temp = ifelse(V(macaque)$shape=="square", 0, 1)
macaque = delete_vertex_attr(macaque, "shape")
V(macaque)$shape = temp
```

Now the shapes will be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Found a solution based on this answer [Change attributes of one node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587903/change-attributes-of-one-node)

```
 V(macaque)$shape[which(V(macaque)$shape=="square")]=0
 V(macaque)$shape[which(V(macaque)$shape=="circle")]=1
```

Edit: Just realized that it doesn't convert the data into numeric but keeps it as a character.